# dynamic table for team members assigning shift colors between selected date range

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a table for my team members which displays shifts for next month. I have two inputs - date range and shift name. Once the team member enters all the details, based on the selected date range that particular cells in the table will be colored. 
**Context :** I have 6 team members and I'm making a shift calendar for April 2023, so the columns would be 31 and rows will be 6. Now I'm selecting date range as 01/04/2023 to 05/04/2023 and shift as evening, in the table cells from 1st column (1st April will be 1st column) to 5th column would be colored. 
**Question:** How can I change the color of the cell based on the date range selected ?

**Design would be like this:**
[image]

**Code used:**

```
function addTable() {
    var myTableDiv = document.getElementById("ShiftTableContainer");
    const startDate = new Date($parameters.StartDate);
    const endDate = new Date($parameters.EndDate);
    const diffTime = Math.abs(endDate - startDate);
    const diffDays = Math.ceil(diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); 
    alert(diffTime);
    alert(diffDays);
    var table = document.createElement('TABLE');
    table.border = '1';
    var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY');
    table.appendChild(tableBody);
    for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        var tr = document.createElement('TR');
        tableBody.appendChild(tr);
        for (var j = 1; j <= diffDays; j++) {
            var td = document.createElement('TD');
            td.width = '75';
            td.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Cell " + i + "," + j));
            tr.appendChild(td);
            td.setAttribute("id",""+i+j);
        }
    }
    myTableDiv.appendChild(table);
}
addTable();
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @DBS I missed the last line. I've updated it. Apologies.